# Letter frequency program Hashmap with Key as integer, Value as Character

Tags: java, treemap

I am writing a letter frequency program and due to certain requirements I am to write the hashmap so that the Key is an Integer, and the Value is a Character. I am able to write the hashmap entries the other way around like the following:

```
 TreeMap<Character,Integer> treeMapTrial = new TreeMap<Integer, Character>();
for(int i = 0; i < fileString.length(); i++){
 char ch = fileString.charAt(i);
Integer valueOfMap = treeMapTrial.get(new Character(ch));
if(valueOfMap !=null)
{
if(Character.isLetter(ch))
      {
hashMap.put(ch, new Integer(valueOfMap+1));
      }
   }else
   {
     {  
       if(Character.isLetter(ch))
     {
        hashMap.put(ch,1);  
     } 
   }
}
```

However I'm having troubles writing it the other way so that Integer is the Key, and character is value
Thanks

Comment: If the frequency becomes the key, how do you intend to handle two characters having the same frequency?

Comment: I suggest you add the actual requirements to your question. There's usually a reason or a constraint somewhere there.